# how to include .inc files in drupal8 in custom form

Tags: files

I have my custom module in drupal8.I have created a custom form.My form has many fields so i was wanted to move it to .inc files.Please can someone suggest me how and where to include my .inc file.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`FormStateInterface::loadInclude`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AloadInclude/8.0.x):

> Ensures an include file is loaded whenever the form is processed.
>
> Use this function instead of `module_load_include()` from inside a form constructor or any form processing logic as it ensures that the include file is loaded whenever the form is processed. In contrast to using `module_load_include()` directly, this method makes sure the include file is correctly loaded also if the form is cached.

e.g.

```
// Load node.admin.inc from Node module.
$form_state->loadInclude('node', 'inc', 'node.admin');
```

Answer (score 2):

The procedural function for include files seems still to exists [`module_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/8.3.x), but you shouldn't use it in a form class. Normally you would refactor the code inside of the form class in multiple class methods. If you want an extra file, then create a new class and include it in your form class with an use statement. Each class has it's own file, which is autoloaded with PSR-4, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/psr-4-namespaces-and-autoloading-in-drupal-8

A Trait is an alternative option. You would put the refactored methods in an extra Trait file, but logical the methods remain class methods and at the same time are reusable by other classes. The Traits are also autoloaded. See https://drupalize.me/blog/201503/dependency-injection-traits-drupal-8

Comment: `module_load_include` isn't recommended for forms because it fails in some situations when they're cached. Totally agree with the rest of the advice, but if OP wants to continue including the file the form state object has a method on it to help

Comment: @Clive, great, didn't know about this. But I think this is to include old legacy code, probably not a good idea when you write new code.

Comment: Yeah I'm inclined to agree. I think there are a couple of edge cases that would still be valid (batch callbacks outside the .module file were a concern in D7 for example), but probably won't be by the time Drupal 9 or 10 hits. Best to refactor now